# авторизация с hash

Tags: php

Я понимаю, что про это много написано, но я не могу найти ошибку в своем коде.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include '../db.php';
    $login = strip_tags($_POST['login']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ( $row1 = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $login_in_data = $row1['login'];
        $name_in_data = $row1['name'];
    }
} catch (exeption $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } 


if ( $login == $login_in_data ) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE login = (:login) ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':login', $login);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ( $row2 = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $password_in_data = $row2['password'];
    }
    if ( password_verify($password,$password_in_data) ) { // Не работает
        // Если пользователь зашел (тк логин и пароль правильные)
        echo "Вы вошли, как " . $login;
    } else {
        // Если пользователь не зашел (тк логин и пароль правильные)
        echo "Пароль не правильный! ";
        echo "Ваш пароль: " . $password;
        echo " Пароль с базы данных: " . $password_in_data;
    }
} else {
    echo "Логин не правильный!";
}
?>
```

Строка, которая не хочет работать помечена комментарием.

**$password** - пароль, который ввёл пользователь
**$password_in_data** - пароль, хранящийся в базе данных

По структуре так и нужно, чтобы в 1 части был пароль, введённый пользователем, а после запятой - пароль, который хранится в БД. Но он пишет false, хотя пароль верен.. Прошу помочь

Comment: А как генерите хеш перед записью в базу? `password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`?

Comment: зачем вы в начале выбираете всех пользователей с базы, и сохраняете в переменную последнего из выборки?

Comment: @Suvitruf  вот как он при регистрации генерируется:  https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey995/ctq2xr4L/

Comment: @teran я эту часть кода удалю, это я проверял правильно ли я вообще пароль с БД доставал :)

Comment: @teran у него в таблице только 1 пользователь :)

Comment: @Cool_cool может `bindParam` нужно вызывать до генерации хеша? У вас в базе точно хеш хранится?

Comment: @Suvitruf зачем?

Comment: @Ипатьев откуда вы знаете, что у меня в таблице 1 пользователь?

Comment: @Ипатьев не знаю, в нормальном языке обычно сначала вычисляют значение, а потом биндят. Я про код с jsfiddle, если что, а не про код из вопроса.

Comment: Я ужасный маг и волшебник. Вижу код на расстоянии, а нерадивых похапешников превращаю в тыкву.

Comment: @Ипатьев о великий и могучий, помогите мне понять что не так в моем коде :d

Comment: @Ипатьев порекомендуете?

Comment: я добавил в заголовок вопроса еще одну ссылку

Comment: @Ипатьев у меня в бд в пароле стоит varchar(256), ничего не урезается. А 1 ссылка - там он просто перестал выводить пароль с бд. Вы не могли бы просто указать - что конкретнее не так у меня в коде??

Comment: Password-verify ожидает пароль и хэш, а не пароль и пароль http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php. Правильно будет сопоставить $password === $password_in_data

Comment: @Алексей Но.. если я захеширую введенный пароль заного при авторизации и вставлю как проверку хеша, то он никогда не совпадет ибо хеш всегда выдает разное даже с одним и тем же паролем. Чуть поконкретнее, пожалуйста!

Comment: Я привёл пример и ссылку. Куда конкретнее?

Comment: @Cool_cool читайте внимательнее документацию, ссылку на которую Вам дали выше, *password_hash() возвращает алгоритм, стоимость и соль как части хеша. Таким образом, вся необходимая для проверки информация включена в него*